# Tap Action script in Lua giving error

Tags: android, image, lua, watchmaker

im trying to create a simple tap action in lua for a watch face im creating with watchmaker to change one image to another. Basically the idea is, when i tap on the Image1 it will change to Image2. But when i add the code to the editor, **it gives me the error '< eof >' expected near '='**
The code is as below.

```
var_image=0
var_opacity1=100
var_opacity2=0

function change()
 var_image=var_image}+1

 if var_image==0 then
  var_opacity1=100
  var_opacity2=0
 end

 if var_image==1 then
  var_opacity1=0
  var_opacity2=100
 end

 if var_image==2 then
  var_image=0
 end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error is somewhere else.  Please show the whole code.

Comment: i managed to solve it. the problem was with another set of codes as you suggested. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 var_image=var_image}+1
```

to

```
 var_image=var_image+1
```